# Async action hangs/deadlocks, why? (not waiting for Result, nor ConfiguringAwait)

Tags: c#, async-await, deadlock

First, sorry for yet another "why my async action hangs" question but I believe this question is different enough. 
Surveying dozens of similar questions, the problem of async action deadlock is either in locking yourself out (`.Result`), using limited resources or using library components incorrectly (web requests seems popular). In the following example, I cannot find *any from above*:

```
private async Task ExecuteAsync(Task<int> task)
{
    // entering on current thread, that is the main UI thread
    await task // execute "task" asynchronnously (on a different thread)
        .ConfigureAwait(false); // when done, no need to return to main thread
    MessageBox.Show("success"); // succes indicator
}

public MainWindow() //wpf window ctor
{            
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var task = new Task<int>(() => 42); // make an Action wrapping sychronnous method
    // fire and forget, never caring for .Result, disard even the task
    var _ = ExecuteAsync(task).ConfigureAwait(false); 
}
```

I have commented the sample with my best try on exaplaining how things (should) work, but something in my explanation must be wrong. Even though `MainWindow` ctor does not deadlock, the Action `() => 42` is never executed and "success" message is not shown. After some debugging I managed to fix the sample (using `Task.FromResult`), but I am still not sure what is wrong with it as it is now and even more importantly why.
What is the error in my reasoning and why was the action never executed/finished?

Comment: Don't call async methods from a constructor.

Comment: @mason Using constructor just to make the sample shorter/better readable, same problem occurs in `Button.Click` handler.

Comment: Then do it from a button click handler, where it's acceptable to do async void. Don't call async methods from a constructor.

Comment: There is no `await` in your code in `MainWindow_Loaded`

Comment: @mason this should be regarded as "Minimal Reproducible Example", it should not be regarded as actual piece of codebase, and the structure is not meant to do anything meaningful (except returning 42 as the answer). If more context helps, the actual code is is RESTful http request callback continuation using asynchronnous binding wrapper to provide literal as a fallback value. (but I guess nobody would want to read **that** sample)

Comment: @wondra I know what a Minimal Reproducible Example is. However, the example is not nearly as useful if you violate a common rule of async: don't do it from the constructor. Simplifying your example so much that it breaks common rules makes it much less useful. Follow the basic rules of async: don't call async methods from constructors, don't do async void unless you're in an event handler, don't use .Result, always await your result.

Comment: @mason oops....

Comment: @wondra your example has no running task. It's all synchronous, and the last step awaits a cold (ie non-running) task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not **start** the task! You only declared it. Simply `await`ing it does not "fire" it.

```
private async Task ExecuteAsync(Task<int> task)
{
    // at first do start the task
    task.Start();

    await task.ConfigureAwait(false); 
    MessageBox.Show("success");
}
```

---

Note that `ConfigureAwait(false)` does not guarantee that execution will be continued on a different thread. It only says that you don't *need* it to be resumed on the original thread. And resuming UI work (like `MessageBox.Show()`) on a non-UI thread is not recommended.

---

As [NineBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178135/async-action-hangs-deadlocks-why-not-waiting-for-result-nor-configuringawait/59178273#comment104578072_59178273) pointed out, if you want to wrap a synchronous method and let it run on a different thread, you should use `Task.Run()`:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => YourSynchronousCall());
```

Comment: I intended like to start the task in `ExecuteAsync` (if not already running but skipped that check, assuming it is not), does that mean that the error in my reasoning is that `await task;` does not actually start the task?

Comment: @wondra yes, the task's `Status` is only `Created` until you `Start()` it. Then it's `WaitingToRun`, `Running` and `Completed`.

Comment: @wondra But I don't know about your real code. If you really only wrapped a synchronous call like you showed in your example, then this is probably your problem. A `Task` returned from an `async` method is of course already `Running`.

Comment: It's also important to note that in this situation the Task will be executed on the same thread. There will not be any asynchronicity, unless a different TaskScheduler is used or Task.Run or some other method of actually making the task run on another thread.

Comment: Thank you very much, I assumed there is not difference between `new Task<int>` and passing call result of `async Task<int> Method()` since, it returns a `Task<int>` (not knowing it is a *running* task). A bit counterintuitive.

Comment: As a side-note, if you use `Task.FromResult(42);`, then you don't need to start the task explicitly. It will be given the Completed state immediately.

Comment: @RenéVogt the actual code is trying to use bindable `Task` wrapper with either http request(working) or optimizing the call by passing cached value from sychronnous method (not working, the problematic sample). Solved it quickly using `Task.FromResult`, but was curious what was the issue.

Comment: Maybe this is why creating cold tasks by using the `Task` constructor has fallen out of favor. It makes things more complex. Life is easier if you can safely assume that everytime you are handled a task it's in a hot (running) state.